# Why does a 308 Redirect not automatically redirect to the URL in location as 301/302 do?

Tags: c#, redirect, error-handling, bots, http-status-codes

I have a BOT that scrapes certain data and sometimes they get their pages wrong e.g for two different times they will have a different no of items but the same main info date/time/place etc.

I log all of the URLS on a first crawl but tonight when I was re-running instead of the site just leaving those incorrect pages with an error message which I was handling it was returning WebException 308 Permanent Redirect and not actually following it as my BOT does on 301/302 redirects.

I've never come across 308's before but thought they would handle just like 301/302 and take my BOT to that new location but it's an error instead.

Should I try and handle the 308, remove it from my dataset and carry on.
Set a flag in the recordset due to the times being so close together and be wary of crawling those pages incase a 308 comes up and just ignore it.
Or some other method.

I just don't why it wouldn't redirect automatically like 301/302s.

The BOT is in C# and has thousands of lines of code - too much to put 1% worth in this box if you're asking for examples.

It's just a normal WebRequest get the response, status, code, check for errors, and status codes, and returns the HTML or the error, or if set to, retries with a different random proxy/referer/useragent etc before stopping.

Comment: A 308 with not Location Header set may suggest that the Server is misconfigured, it could be actually a 200 (it happens sometimes) or the Server is no longer hosing that Site, which may have moved to another hosting service. The two parties may have agreed on redirecting to the new Host, but the previous service is not fulfilling the request or the Site's owners ware supposed to provide the redirection URI when the Site was moved (an automated, possibly temporary, action), but they never did (or haven't yet).

Comment: As a note, the RFC states that the Server *should* (not *must*) provide a Location Header, but a service may be setup to send a HTML that contains the redirection. The service may be also not be accurately configured, so it sends a 308 instead of a 301 (edge case).

Comment: So no easy way for my BOT to just follow redirections then

Comment: It depends. What happens if you use a WebBrowser to navigate to that URI? Does it redirect? With what Status Code? 301 or 308? If it can redirect, check the Status Code of the redirection. The redirection can be set, as mentioned, in the HTML (meta Refresh) or with a JavaScript -- Do you present your BOT as such, using the `bot` keyword in the User-Agent string? If you do or the service detects a bot (sending a challenge, or using HTTP 2.0 HSTS or similar), it may set 308 instead of 301 to prevent a change from POST to GET (less secure). Many possible variations.

Comment: I don't use the word BOT as I don't want it to get blocked, I use karmic scraping guidelines as in not overloading their server with requests, waiting between attempts, respecting robots.txt. They try to prevent BOTS from scraping data by adding on the fly gibbersih class values to stop regex that is too specific e.g <span class="xy35799ff ewwfjj3rkk wejjwejf"><sup>1</sup>st</span> and often changing spans to divs to ps on the fly. I have fixed it with code that returns the 308 and adds the URL to a DB table so it's ignored on future crawls. Web browser follows ok. 308 not shown in network...

Comment: console when looking at all the files loaded in and any redirects. I cannot see any redirection done by JS or HTML META and my BOT handles redirection by META refresh, body onload, window onload, inline or script, with or without a setTimeout function to delay the onload function call. I have the web developer options open and this only happens rarely for some reason. There are obvious ways to spot a spurious event such as saying there are 8 items but showing 28, not showing all the data that a normal page does, plus the time of the event is always 5-10 mins away from the correct item page.